# Linux btrfs how to remove unexistent filesystem from list?

Tags: linux, btrfs

I'm giving a try to btrfs. I did some mistakes, which are good for learning!

I created several btrfs filesystems upon different devices (sdX, loop, lvm, etc). During these tests, I removed (abruptly) some or all devices which were part of a btrfs filesystem (fs were unmounted first).

But now, command `btrfs show` still shows filesystems UUID and list of devices.
I understand that I should have done a `btfrs device del` BEFORE removing devices...

But where does btrfs stores its list of handled filesystems? Is there a conf file somewhere? A special command in btrfs-tools?

I didn't come with a comprehensive answer reading wiki and tutos... It is said that we can recover a dead filesystem and mounting it with `mount -o recovery /dev/yourBTFSvolume /mount/point` but that implies metadata/data and related devices still exist, which isn't the case here.

Here I do not attempt to recover data, I just want to clean btrfs management.

Comment: Just nuke the leftovers with `wipefs`.

Comment: I think `wipefs` won't apply in this case: it needs a device to wipe to. Here devices are no more available or are used in another fs. There's just the UUID which keep re-appearing at each boot.

Answer (score 3):

I poked around in the code to see what was going on. When the `btrfs filesystem show` command is used to show all filesystems on all devices, it scans every device and partition in `/proc/partitions`. Each device and each partition is examined to see if there is a BTRFS "magic number" and associated valid root data structure found at 0x10040 offset from the beginning of the device or partition.

I then used hexedit on a disk that was showing up wrongly in my own situation and sure enough there was a BTRFS magic number (which is the ASCII string `_BHRfS_M`) there from my previous experiments.

I simply nailed that magic number by overwriting a couple of the characters of the string with "**", also using hexedit, and the wrong entries magically disappeared!

Comment: Exactly that's the correct way. How to do it using `wipefs` or `dd`: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Problem_FAQ#How_to_clean_up_old_superblock_.3F